# Sphinx (rest): maintaining the number count in the numbered list when two files are included

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have one .rst file include other two .rst files, and those files have

for example:

```
.. include:: first.rst

.. include:: second.rst
```

And the two files have a numbered list:

```
#. List test
```

But when I compile a latex or a html output, the number is reset for the list in the `second.rst`. Is there any way to make the numbers continue? (So the list from the `first.rst` starts with 1 while the one from the `second.rst` starts from 2?)